# Script FTP - Prompt Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp, prompt

I want to create an FTP script will from a file list. For this I created a file called Gerar_Lista.cmd and within it have the command lines:

```
echo User> subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
echo PassWord >> subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
for / f% i in (verifica.txt) echo% i put /content/UPLOAD/%~nxi>>subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
echo bye >> subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
```

The problem is that when I run the Gerar_Lista.cmd file to create my FTP script, they generate only the first two lines (example below). How do I generate it the FTP script altogether?

```
user
PassWord
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompt Windows - Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924565/prompt-windows-script)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong in your for loop. Use double %% signs for the variables when calling from a batch file. And there should have been a `do` after the brackets.

```
echo User> subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
echo PassWord >> subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
for /f %%i in (verifica.txt) do echo %%i put /content/UPLOAD/%%~nxi>>subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
echo bye >> subir_arquivos_xml.ftp
```