# Prompt Windows - Script

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp

I have a folder (`essa é nova pasta`) with multiple .txt files in it

```
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
```

The folder is a name that has accent (`essa é a nova pasta`) and made a script to generate a list of all the .txt files, but looked like this:

```
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa ‚ nova pasta\35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt.
```

I need to create an FTP script to make a put to from the list of .txt files. generated above. I used the FOR command and begot the list but it came out like this:

```
user
password
put "C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa ‚ nova pasta\35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt" /content/UPLOAD/35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
bye
```

He gave a message that the file does not exist, because it does not recognize the name of the folder (`essa ‚ nova pasta`)

I need my FTP script exit as the folder name "this is new folder", ie, with the correct name and manages my FTP script correctly as follows:

```
user
password
put "C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\ 35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt" /content/UPLOAD/35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
bye
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: FTP and accented characters is not a great idea for a recipe.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Why do you generate a file list, why don't you use `mput *.txt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script Prompt Windows - List Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965316/script-prompt-windows-list-files)

Answer (score 0):

If all your files come from "C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\" then you can (once, at the top) run

```
lcd "C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\
```

That way you're not manipulating the accented character in a `for` loop.

Then your put statements will look like this:

```
put 35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt /content/UPLOAD/35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
```

If all your files need to end up in the remote directory `/content/UPLOAD/` then you can further simplify by changing to that directory in the ftp command like this:

```
cd /content/UPLOAD
```

Then your put statement looks like this:

```
put 35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
```

You don't need to specify the filename twice that way.
So to transfer these files:

```
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\anotherfile.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\yetanotherfile.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\onemorefile.txt
```

to the remote server's directory `/content/UPLOAD`:

```
user
password
lcd "C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\"
cd /content/UPLOAD
put 35160101660296000130550020000540011858610314.txt
put anotherfile.txt
put yetanotherfile.txt
put onemorefile.txt
bye
```

Comment: My files can come from multiple folder and not just the folder that I said above (this is new folder). I have several others in the C: \ xml \ UPDATE \ ... .Preciso ensure that the Update process does not stop if I have to process files within several subfolders in the C: \ xml \ UPDATE \. Must identify with folder names that have accents to ensure that my FTP script does not do put the .txt files

Comment: Then let's look at your `for` loop and see why it's mangling your é