# Script Prompt Windows - List Files

Tags: windows, cmd

I have several .txt files in multiple directories. I need to create a list of these .txt files, but as I have directories that have names with accents, to create the list, these names come out the wrong way out comma and £ in the name of the directories. Example below:

```
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35160101660296000130550020000540011858638110.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35160101660296000130550020000540011858638511.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35160101660296000130550020000540011858638603.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa ‚ nova pasta\ 35160101660296000130550020000540011858664656.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa ‚ nova pasta\ 35160101660296000130550020000540011858664810.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\pasta n£mero 3\35160101660296000130550020000540011858624546.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\pasta n£mero 3\35160101660296000130550020000540011858624848.txt
```

The Right would leave as shown below:

```
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35160101660296000130550020000540011858638110.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35160101660296000130550020000540011858638511.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\35160101660296000130550020000540011858638603.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\35160101660296000130550020000540011858664656.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\essa é nova pasta\35160101660296000130550020000540011858664810.txt
C:\xml\UPLOAD\pasta número 3\35160101660296000130550020000540011858624546.txt
C:\ xml\UPLOAD\pasta número 3\35160101660296000130550020000540011858624848.txt
```

How do I handle this problem?

Comment: Try typing `chcp 1252`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the code page to 1252 which should work.

```
chcp 1252
dir /b /s *.txt
```

http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html